# How to display multiple rows for one id in MySql?

Tags: mysql

I have a table similar with this one [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXOmj.png)

Is it possible to display the ID only once?
So the expected result will be a table with 2 rows, but the id wont be displayed twice, only once.

I didn't write any code because I dont know where to start from.

Comment: What is the primary key of your table?

Comment: I don't have a primary key for this table. It's supposed to be a table where i register all the  logins made by POST_ID.

Comment: Thank you for suggesting that possible duplicate! :)

Comment: I would suggest you to create a trigger that after inserting in your table verifies POST_ID and if already exists replaces that row (to store the last login)

Comment: I don't want to replace the duplicates, i want to display all of them, but id don't want to display each time the id.

Comment: So, in that example what you want is a row with ID = 1 and the other one with a blank ID?

Comment: Exactly. That's what I want.

Comment: In that case you can always use a trigger that when a row is inserted, if that POST_ID is already displayed you update that row and set the value that you want to display (in this case: `SET column = ''`)

Comment: Thank you, I will try it that way.